# An exercise on limsup and liminf

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

when I was catching up with Evans PDE and I realise I do not have a good understanding about limsup and liminf.

I found the following exercise in a real analysis book that motivates the definition of limsup.But I have no idea how to answer.

Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence. For each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let

$$y_k=\sup_{n\ge k} x_n=\sup\{x_k,x_{k+1},x_{k+2},\cdots\}.$$

1. Show that the sequence $(y_k)$ is decreasing and bounded below.
2. Conclude that $(y_k)$ converges.

[Part 1) was solved in previous posts, but I have not found an answer for part 2)]

Comment: Can you at least go from (1) to (2)?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*
The second one follows from the first. The intuition behind $\limsup$ ($\liminf$ as well) is this: take $\sup_{n \geq 1}x_{n}$; delete $x_{1}$ and take $\sup_{n \geq 2}x_{n}$; delete $x_{2}$ and take $\sup_{n \geq 3}x_{n}$; repeat this process indefinitely. Clearly, we have $n_{1} > n_{2}$ only if $\{ x_{n} \mid n \geq n_{1}\} \subset \{ x_{n} \mid n \geq n_{2} \}$ and only if 
$\sup_{n \geq n_{1}}x_{n} \leq \sup_{n \geq n_{2}}x_{n}$; hence the sequence $(\sup_{n \geq N}x_{n})_{N \geq 1}$ is decreasing.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: is it a reference for this, it is a bit too abstract to understand

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_k := \{x_k, x_{k+1}, \ldots \}$. Then by definition, $y_k = \sup S_k$. Notice that $S_{k} \supseteq S_{k+1}$. Therefore $\sup S_k \geq \sup S_{k+1}$, i.e. $y_k \geq y_{k+1}$ for all $k$. If this doesn't click for you right away, you need to spend more time thinking about it on your own .

The sequence $\{y_k\}$ is bounded below because, in particular, $y_k \geq \inf \{x_1, x_2, \ldots\}$ for every $k$, and that infimum is finite since $\{x_k\}$ is a bounded sequence.

Part 2 of your question is a standard fact which I would encourage you to spend more time thinking about on your own.

Comment: I got stuck from your first sentence? Could you please explain (or find another way to phase what you meant) By the way, your hint looks plausible for me to make a start and I will need  to spend some time once I understand every sentence you wrote.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to make it more precise

Comment: okay take your time, i need to find a quiet place to read too.

Comment: ok. reading it line by line. The first sentence make sense, as the least upper bound of a bigger set should be no smaller than that of a smaller set. Hence $y_k\ge y_{k+1}$.

Comment: I don't quite follow your reasoning about why $\{y_k\}$ is bounded below, do you mean $y_k\ge\inf\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{k-1}\}$ for every $k$?

Comment: for part ii of my question, $y_k$ converges to the $\inf\{\cdots\}$

Comment: Because $\sup_{n\ge k} x_n=y_k$ is decreasing and bounded below, one can regard the limit supremum of $x_n$ as the infimum of $\sup_{n\ge k} x_n$ over all $k$

Comment: I do not mean that that $y_k \geq \inf \{x_1, \ldots, x_{k-1}\}$. I mean that $y_k$ is greater or equal to the infinite set that I wrote in my answer. See if you can prove to yourself why what I wrote is correct.

Comment: $y_k$ will not necessarily (in fact, not usually) converge to $\inf \{x_1, x_2, \ldots\}$. What is true instead is that every monotone bounded sequence converges. This is the standard fact which you should prove on your own if you have not done so already.

Comment: I am still confused about your reasoning on "The sequence $y_k$ bounded below bit. And I am lost about how to prove that $y_k$ bigger than the infinite set bit. But yes I understand the standard fact in your last comment.

Comment: I mistyped. I meant that $y_k$ is greater than or equal to the infimum of the infinite set which I used in my answer. This is obvious since $y_k$ is the supremum of a subset of that set. I really can't say anything more useful than that.

Comment: no you didn't mistype, if the infinite set has a infimum (greatest lower bound) then it must be bounded below.

Comment: Basically, $\{x_k,x_{k+1},\cdots\}\subseteq\{x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$, then it is true that $\inf\{x_1,x_2,\cdots\}\le\inf\{x_k,x_{k+1},\cdots\}\le y_k=\sup_{n\ge k} x_n=\sup\{x_k,x_{k+1},\cdots\}\le \sup\{x_1,x_2,\cdots\}.$ But how does this help to prove $y_k=\sup_{n\ge k} x_n=\sup\{x_k,x_{k+1},\cdots\}$ converges?